# How to differentiate GADT constructors with different phantom types?

Tags: haskell, gadt

I'm working on a system (inspired by [lsp-types](https://github.com/alanz/lsp/tree/master/lsp-types)) that uses GADTs tagged with type information to represent the different types of messages exchanged by a client and server:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, RankNTypes #-}

data From = FromClient | FromServer
data MessageType = Request | Notification

data Message (from :: From) (typ :: MessageType) where
  Request1 :: Message FromClient Request
  Request2 :: Message FromClient Request
  Request3 :: Message FromServer Request
  Notification1 :: Message FromClient Notification
```

My question is, given a list of these constructors (in an existential wrapper), how can I select a subset of them that have a certain type?

```hs
data SomeMessage where
  SomeMessage :: forall f t. Message f t -> SomeMessage

allMessages = [SomeMessage Request1
              , SomeMessage Request2
              , SomeMessage Request3
              , SomeMessage Notification1]

-- Desired output: [SomeMessage Request1, SomeMessage Request2, SomeMessage Request3]
filterToRequests :: [SomeMessage] -> [SomeMessage]
filterToRequests allMessages = undefined 

-- Desired output: [SomeMessage Request1, SomeMessage Request2]
filterToClientRequests :: [SomeMessage] -> [SomeMessage]
filterToClientRequests allMessages = undefined
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include the required language features for people trying to run it themselves (GADTs, DataKinds, RankNTypes, KindSignatures)

Comment: Oh sorry, missed those when copying and pasting -- added!

Comment: Your functions fall afoul of [Parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/). You should consider adding `data SomeRequest where SomeRequest :: forall f. Message f Request -> SomeRequest`, and changing your functions' types to `filterToRequests :: [SomeMessage] -> [SomeRequest]` and `filterToClientRequests :: [SomeMessage] -> [Message FromClient Request]`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I wish I could, see my follow-up comment on the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this just using `cast` from `Data.Typeable`.  In particular, if you have:

```
data SomeMessage where
  SomeMessage :: forall f t. (Typeable f, Typeable t) => Message f t -> SomeMessage

data SomeMessageRequest where
  SomeMessageRequest :: forall f. Message f Request -> SomeMessageRequest
```

(noting the `Typeable` dictionaries in `SomeMessage`), you can use scoped type variables and type applications to write:

```
maybeRequest :: SomeMessage -> Maybe SomeMessageRequest
maybeRequest (SomeMessage (msg :: Message f t))
  = SomeMessageRequest <$> cast @_ @(Message f Request) msg
```

to get:

```
allRequests :: [SomeMessageRequest]
allRequests = catMaybes $ map maybeRequest allMessages
```

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Maybe

data From = FromClient | FromServer
data MessageType = Request | Notification

data Message (from :: From) (typ :: MessageType) where
  Request1 :: Message FromClient Request
  Request2 :: Message FromClient Request
  Request3 :: Message FromServer Request
  Notification1 :: Message FromClient Notification

data SomeMessage where
  SomeMessage :: forall f t. (Typeable f, Typeable t) => Message f t -> SomeMessage

data SomeMessageRequest where
  SomeMessageRequest :: forall f. Message f Request -> SomeMessageRequest

allMessages = [ SomeMessage Request1
              , SomeMessage Request2
              , SomeMessage Request3
              , SomeMessage Notification1]

maybeRequest :: SomeMessage -> Maybe SomeMessageRequest
maybeRequest (SomeMessage (msg :: Message f t))
  = SomeMessageRequest <$> cast @_ @(Message f Request) msg

allRequests :: [SomeMessageRequest]
allRequests = catMaybes $ map maybeRequest allMessages
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution utilizes the fact that `GADT` constructors expose any existential type constraints in their scope upon pattern matching. The trick was to introduce two type classes `KnownSender` and `KnownType` that allow to convert their respective kind variables to runtime values:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

data From = FromClient | FromServer deriving (Eq)
data MessageType = Request | Notification deriving (Eq)

data Message (from :: From) (typ :: MessageType) where
  Request1 :: Message 'FromClient 'Request
  Request2 :: Message 'FromClient 'Request
  Request3 :: Message 'FromServer 'Request
  Notification1 :: Message 'FromClient 'Notification

data SomeMessage where
  SomeMessage :: forall f t. KnownTags f t => Message f t -> SomeMessage

class KnownSender (f :: From) where
  knownSenderVal :: From

instance KnownSender 'FromClient where
  knownSenderVal = FromClient
instance KnownSender 'FromServer where
  knownSenderVal = FromServer
    
class KnownType (t :: MessageType) where
  knownTypeVal :: MessageType

instance KnownType 'Request where
  knownTypeVal = Request
instance KnownType 'Notification where
  knownTypeVal = Notification

type KnownTags f t = (KnownSender f, KnownType t)

knownTags :: SomeMessage -> (From,MessageType)
knownTags (SomeMessage msg) = knownTags' msg -- Magic happens here!
  where
    -- This function may also be written at the top level should you need it.
    knownTags' :: forall f t . KnownTags f t => Message f t -> (From, MessageType)
    knownTags' _ = (knownSenderVal @f ,knownTypeVal @t)

allMessages = [SomeMessage Request1
              , SomeMessage Request2
              , SomeMessage Request3
              , SomeMessage Notification1]

-- Desired output: [SomeMessage Request1, SomeMessage Request2, SomeMessage Request3]
filterToRequests :: [SomeMessage] -> [SomeMessage]
filterToRequests = filter ((== Request) . snd . knownTags)
-- Desired output: [SomeMessage Request1, SomeMessage Request2]
filterToClientRequests :: [SomeMessage] -> [SomeMessage]
filterToClientRequests = filter ((== FromClient) . fst . knownTags)
```

Take note that your `SomeMessage` type had to be slightly modified to include the `KnownTags` constraint in its constructor. the `Eq` instances for both `From` and `MessageType` were also added.

**Update:**

As per your comment, if you need to have a `[SomeMessage] -> [SomeRequestMessage]` function, one way is to use reflection:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Type.Reflection (TypeRep,Typeable,typeRep,eqTypeRep)
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Maybe (maybeToList)

-- Add Typeable constraints for f and t
type KnownTags f t = (Typeable f,KnownSender f, Typeable t, KnownType t)

-- General utility function useful for dynamic programming and reflection
withKnownMsg :: forall a . SomeMessage -> (forall f t . KnownTags f t => Message f t -> a) -> a
withKnownMsg (SomeMessage msg) f = f msg

data SomeRequestMessage where
  SomeRequestMessage :: forall f. KnownTags f 'Request => Message f 'Request -> SomeRequestMessage

toSomeRequest :: SomeMessage -> Maybe SomeRequestMessage
toSomeRequest someMsg = withKnownMsg someMsg f
  where
    f :: forall f t . (KnownTags f t) => Message f t -> Maybe SomeRequestMessage
    f msg = fmap (\HRefl -> SomeRequestMessage msg). eqTypeRep (typeRep @t) $ typeRep @'Request

someRequestMsgs :: [SomeMessage] -> [SomeRequestMessage]
someRequestMsgs msgs = msgs >>= (maybeToList . toSomeRequest)
```

Comment: This is the pattern I would generally use. If you need to reify `From` and `MessageType` at the type level, a typical form is `data SFrom (f :: From) where { SFromClient :: SFrom 'FromClient; SFromServer :: SFrom 'FromServer }`. That pattern can be derived using the [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) package, which provides many other type-level goodies like dependent sums (`Sigma`). These `KnownSender` & `KnownType` classes would become `SingI 'From` & `SingI 'MessageType`, and you’d access the values with `demote` (or equivalently `fromSing sing`).

Comment: I'm a little scared of singletons since it says it requires GHC 8.10.1+. But I am having a little trouble with the current solution because the `knownTags` function doesn't come with type-level information about the constructor. For example, I would like to pattern match on the tags to find all `Request` types, and then package those in a new wrapper `SomeRequestMessage` which only holds requests. But that doesn't work at present. I might try to get singletons to derive the `SFrom`-like versions and try to use those, but would welcome suggestions...

Comment: @tom Only singletons 2.7 needs GHC 8.10.1+. Older versions of it work with older versions of GHC.

Comment: So I tried singletons 2.6, but didn't get any further than writing `genSingletons [''Message]`. The generated code fails to compile with `Expected kind ‘From’, but ‘f_aJcY’ has kind ‘*’`. Maybe singletons 2.6 can't handle the kind signatures?

Comment: @tom I updated to answer to address your further issue mentioned in the comment

Comment: Ah, very cool, I had a feeling Data.Type.Equality would come into this at some point. Thanks!